# LINQ is giving error: The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect

Tags: linq

My LINQ query is giving following error :

`The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'.`

I have the following LINQ query which is giving the error:

```
from m in array join p in resellers on m equals p.ResellerId into j
//  join p in resellers on new { m }  equals new { p.ResellerId } into j
```

Comment: What is the type of the variable `array`?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what type `array` is, but with the error that you have it is certainly not of the same type as `p.ResellerID`. That's the type inference error that it's giving you. You need to use a property of `m` from your `array` that's of the same type as `p.ResellerID` in order to be able to properly do a join.